# Implementation of Execute and Wait Interceptor on Struts 2 File upload interceptor?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am trying to implement the Struts Execute and wait interceptor on File upload interceptor of struts as I want to show the progress bar showing the file upload progress.

Can anybody help me out in this.

If anybody has better method to do this in struts please suggest where I can create progress bar show file upload progress more effectively.

Comment: have you tried http://code.google.com/p/ajax-file-upload-struts2/. i still not got time to play around with Execute and wait interceptor :(

Comment: no I haven't tried yet... will definitely let you know if somethings works.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out AJAX File Upload using FormData API ?

[You can find the complete documentation and Sample Code Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

You can simply calculate the size of the file using  `ProgressEvent.lengthComputable, ProgressEvent.total` and `ProgressEvent.loaded` attributes.

Note that, IE 9 or Earlier versions do not support the FormData API.